# How to keep entered and selected values after validation error in code-igniter?

Tags: php, validation, continuous-integration

After redirect from error validation other selected fields or input text value getting vanish-out.So i am trying to keep entered and selected values after validation error in code igniter.

i have already tried : set_value, set_select

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" id="code" value="<?php echo set_value('code') ?>">

and

 <option value="CA" <?php echo set_select('country', 'CA', TRUE) ?> >CANADA</option>

and

 <option value="<?php echo $address_value['id']; ?>" <?php echo set_select('address_name', $address_value['id']) ?>><?php echo $final_address; ?></option>
```

To keep other entered or selected field value after coming from error validation on form submit.

Comment: What framework do you use, 'set_value' is not native php function

Comment: Its Code igniter..............................................................